# How do i get this code to scale to different window sizes?

Tags: javascript, css, web, html

I've tried many of the solutions from similar questions but they don't seem to work on my page.This is the code I would like to scale. One more thin, underneath the gif I would like to keep3 boxes per row, as it seems that when I go to a larger window size one of the boxes moves up.

```
<hmtl>
<body>



<style>



* {
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.item {
position: relative;
float:left;
border: 0px solid #333;
margin: 0%;
overflow: hidden;
width: 425px;
}
.item img {
max-width: 100%;

-moz-transition: all 1s;
-webkit-transition: all 1s;
transition: all 1s;
}
.item:hover img {
-moz-transform: scale(1.1);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
transform: scale(1.1);
}

</style>


<div class=“main”>

<img src="http://i.imgur.com/PbeUJ56.gif” style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;" alt=“DESCRIPTION” height=“1280” width=“645”/>




<img src="http://imgur.com/JBWbug1.png" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;" alt=“DESCRITPION” height=“2000” width=“720” alt="" usemap="#Map" /><map name="Map" id="Map">
<area alt="" title="" href="" shape="poly" coords="208,42,47,41,41,132,211,132" />
<area alt="" title="" href="" shape="poly" coords="467,73,467,98,654,99,654,74" />
<area alt="" title="" href=" shape="poly" coords="683,73,685,98,855,97,855,77" />
<area alt="" title="" href="" shape="poly" coords="883,71,883,97,986,96,986,77" />
<area alt="" title="" href="" shape="poly" coords="1007,69,1007,95,1092,95,1091,79"/>
<area alt="" title="" href="" shape="poly" coords="1122,71,1122,100,1230,99,1230,71" /> </map>





<div id="zoom">

<div class="item">
<a href=""><img src="http://imgur.com/jM0ivPh.png" alt="img">
</div>

<div class="item">
<a href=""><img src="http://imgur.com/zMVcoiJ.png" alt="img">
</div>

<div class="item">
<a href=""><img src="http://imgur.com/aVdSekS.png” alt="img" >
</div>

<div class="item">
<a href=""><img src="http://imgur.com/MKjyo1I.png” alt="img" >
</div>

<div class="item">
<a href=""><img src="http://imgur.com/tpYHlOP.png” alt="img" >
</div>

<div class="item">
<a href=""><img src="http://imgur.com/kzy9T7h.png” alt="img" >
</div>

</div>
</div>



<html>
<body>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it "scale" or "respond as you wish, you need to make it responsive.
So instead of setting widths with pixels ("px") use percentages ("%").

so change your ".item" css like so:

```
        .item {
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            border: 0 solid #333;
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 33.3%;
            max-width: 425px;
        }
```

Then you will have to change your main image appropriately too.
However from your code, it seems you might be trying to run before you can walk... Start small and learn the basic of web design and development and build off there, for example:

don't ever do this

```
  * {
    //...
  }
```

instead do this for your requirements:

```
.main div{
   //...
 }
```

don't do in-line styling unless you have to, so this is bad practice:

```
style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;"
```

All "closing tags" must have a forward slash like so:

```
</body>
```

not

```
<body>
```

Close your anchor tags like this:

```
<a href=""><img src="http://imgur.com/jM0ivPh.png" alt="img"></a>
```

not this:

```
<a href=""><img src="http://imgur.com/jM0ivPh.png" alt="img">
```

It's recommended ( <= HTML4 = required) to put style tags inside the "head" element and not the "body" element...

Search for some tutorials, (css, html) and then once you are comfortable, 
find some tutorials on "responsive web design" learn about bootstrap and similarities... Once you know that stuff (it isn't hard) - You will be well on your way to design a great looking responsive web site.

Hope this helps you on your way...

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem. I have fixed the formatting issue using CSS Flexbox. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

I have added a media query at 425px to support the column layout in addition to the grid.

There are a couple small bugs in your code:
1) The closing html and body tags are in reverse order and need forward slashes to close.
2) There is no 'head' in this HTML doc so I added one and moved the CSS into it.
3) Although it is not required, you should end self closing HTML tags such as img tags with a forward slash /. 
4) The 'a' tags need closing tags. 
Here is the working code:

```html
<hmtl>
  <head>
  <style>
  * {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }
  .item {
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  border: 0px solid #333;
  margin: 0%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 425px;
  }
  .item img {
  max-width: 100%;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  }
  .item:hover img {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  .row-1, .row-2 {
    display: flex;   /* This is the fix for the item formatting problem */
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
    .row-1, .row-2 {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
  }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class=“main”>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/PbeUJ56.gif” style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;" alt=“DESCRIPTION” height=“1280” width=“645”/>
    <img src="http://imgur.com/JBWbug1.png" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;" alt=“DESCRITPION” height=“2000” width=“720” alt="" usemap="#Map" />
    <map name="Map" id="Map">
      <area alt="" title="" href="" shape="poly" coords="208,42,47,41,41,132,211,132" />
      <area alt="" title="" href="" shape="poly" coords="467,73,467,98,654,99,654,74" />
      <area alt="" title="" href=" shape="poly" coords="683,73,685,98,855,97,855,77" />
      <area alt="" title="" href="" shape="poly" coords="883,71,883,97,986,96,986,77" />
      <area alt="" title="" href="" shape="poly" coords="1007,69,1007,95,1092,95,1091,79"/>
      <area alt="" title="" href="" shape="poly" coords="1122,71,1122,100,1230,99,1230,71" />
    </map>
    <div id="zoom">
      <div class="row-1">
        <div class="item">
        <a href=""><img src="http://imgur.com/jM0ivPh.png" alt="img" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
        <a href=""><img src="http://imgur.com/zMVcoiJ.png" alt="img" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
        <a href=""><img src="http://imgur.com/aVdSekS.png” alt="img" /></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='row-2'>
        <div class="item">
        <a href=""><img src="http://imgur.com/MKjyo1I.png” alt="img" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
        <a href=""><img src="http://imgur.com/tpYHlOP.png” alt="img" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
        <a href=""><img src="http://imgur.com/kzy9T7h.png” alt="img" /></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

End result: https://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/8fmkg4bq/

One of the key things to remember when is to try not to give fixed width or height to any element if you want it to be fluid (responsive)

So, I went ahead and removed `width` and `height` attributes from the image tags in the markup

To make the image tags fluid, added this css rule:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

First Image (which is a gif) can be used as a background image? So, wen ahead and added a `background` properties to the `.main` container

Which made the second image (png) to overlay on top nicely

Now that the png image is overlayed and fluid. The image map areas are all out of place, which is fixed by using [responsive image maps plugin](http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html)

Regarding the bottom tiles to be fluid at all times and ensuring only 3 tiles are present per row - added `width: 33%` to it `100/3`

Hope this helps ☮